# ios remove sub view from another controller

Tags: ios

I added a sub view from controller A. Now in controller B which is the subview controller, how can I reload view A when the user is done with B? My codes of adding subview:

```
ChangeProfileImage *changeProfileImage =[[ChangeProfileImage alloc] init];  
    changeProfileImage.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    changeProfileImage.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    changeProfileImage.view.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 300, 300);  
    UIView *dimBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    dimBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor grayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:.5f];  
    [self.view addSubview:dimBackgroundView];
    [self.view addSubview:changeProfileImage.view];
```

Comment: so in controller B .. did you try `[self.view removeFromSuperView];` ?

Comment: That works to remove changeprofileimage view but how about the dimbackground view? and how to refresh the controller A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set a tag for "dimbackground" .. and remove it like this:

```
dimBackgroundView.tag = 111;//you will do this line when you create the view.
UIView *view = [controllerA.view viewWithTag:111];
[view removeFromSuperview];
```

To Refresh your viewController :

when the user click the submit button and you remove the B view .. post a notification using `NSNotificationCenter` like this :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"UserSubmit" object:nil];
```

and in controllerA .. viewDidLoad For example add it as observer like this

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(refreshView) name:@"UserSubmit" object:nil];
```

and you will implement this function :

```
- (void) refreshView
{
    //Do your stuff
}
```

Comment: How to refresh controller A view?

Comment: what do you mean by "refresh" ? and when you like to do that?

Comment: that mean user click submit in B. then redirect back to A with the updated values

Comment: UIView *view = [controllerA.view viewWithTag:111]; does not work

Comment: man sure it not will work like this :) .. you have to put correct Values .. controllerA is just an example , put the real name for it.

Comment: Do i need to instantiate controller A in b?

Comment: no you don't .. you can remove "dimBackgroundView" inside the refreshView function.

Comment: ok. one last thing.. many thanks for how help... How can I release the memory allocated to changeprofileimage?

Comment: just after you add its view as a subView .. because addSubView will increase the view reference count by one .. so release it will not make it deallocated.

Comment: no - if i release after added sub view, app crashes when i click a button at the othher end`

Comment: strange ! this is shouldn't be happened .. anyway you can define it the `@interface` .. and release it in the dealloc .. or in the refreshView since you don't need it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

create a button on viewcontroller B with IBAction Connected to it,write the below code in the IBaction of that button,This will remove viewcontroller B

[self.view removeFromSuperview];